# Feasibility of Heroku Concurrency in Interim API Call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, api, heroku

Sorry for the confusing title, it was difficult to come up with one that fit my question.

To explain what I'm trying to do, I'll use an analogous example:
Suppose I wanted to create an API call which, when provided an array of terms, searched Twitter for all of these terms and returned the tweets.

On one hand, I could do something simple, such as (if you'll excuse the pseudo-code):

```
results = []
search_terms.each_with_index do |search_term, i|
  search_uri = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#{search_term}"
  twitter_result = ... #(URI.parse, Net:HTTP:GET, start, etc.)
  results[i] = twitter_result 
end
render :json => results.to_json
```

But, of course, this might be slow if there are a couple dozen keywords - moreso if there are over 100 - because Ruby has to finish waiting for each request to begin the next.

Heroku's dynos seem like they should be able to make this work quickly (for example, the [Dyno Overview](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos) states that "it is possible to originate outgoing requests directly from a dyno"). However, it seems that the means of accessing these tends to be through Delayed Jobs, Resque, etc., which tend to have very different use cases from what I've outlined.

From what I can tell, those means of utilizing multiple dynos/workers won't be workable like typical threads: accessing and modifying instance variables which were instantiated by the caller/parent function. From what I can tell (and correct me if I'm wrong), generally they use their own memory, their own variables, and anything that other functions have to access will be done so through a cache or through the database.

Alright, so that doesn't make this idea impossible. A workaround could be, after creating these `DelayedJobs`, run an indefinite loop (with a timeout) in the parent function that fetches from the DB and checks whether the resulting size is equal to the number of keywords, and otherwise sleep a short period, trying again. The `DelayedJobs` would create these rows after performing their task. It's not a particularly nice solution, and ends up causing a bit of extra work for the server, but as the number of searches increases this would probably be significantly faster than just looping through them.

So here's the question (and a couple related questions, that tie into the first):

What I'm wondering is, how feasible is it to set up a request on Heroku which, upon being called, spins up some new workers quickly, performs  several requests in parallel, and then responds to the caller after all of these requests are complete?

Will the time required to spin up the workers and perform the `DelayedJobs` be too hefty to make this work? (The entire length of the request would, hopefully, only be a few seconds.)

Is there any suggestion about a cut-off number of requests where it's better to just to do them in sequence, rather than use the `DelayedJobs`? (I'd expect not, and that I'd have to do some experimenting and benchmarking for this, to decided at what point to route to either option.)

Have I missed other options that would simplify this process (or, otherwise be more effective)?

**EDIT:** I should note, too, that the additional workers would be spun up on demand using a gem (something like [hirefire](https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire), or similar) - I'm not sure how much this would factor in.

Comment: I did not read everything but if what you need is simply fire multiple requests in parallel you do not need any background process, do you really need the workers ?

Comment: I would need speed (i.e. for them not to just be happing in an odd number, but truly in parallel) and would probably benefit from separate outbound ports. Odds are this is something I'll just have to play around with and test myself, so I'll probably remove the question, was mostly curious about whether I had missed some (obvious or not) better solutions.

Comment: if you plan to be mostly doing I/O you can achieve that with eventmachine in one signel process which can even be the one serving any rails/rack app you may need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving information from external APIs is a blocking task in Ruby, that means, the process or thread you are performing this request in will basically sleep while waiting for a response .

To do a lot of concurrent I/O in the background (like searching Twitter, other HTTP requests etc.) my library of choice in the Ruby/Rails world would be [**Sidekiq**](http://sidekiq.org/). You can read about it's efficiency and advantages over delayed_job and resque in the wiki.

Comment: Yep, the blocking is why I thought of delayed_jobs with additional workers (for IO improvement). It's the basic problem with this type of function. However, sidekiq sounds like it might very well be a better solution to delayed_jobs. I'll probably go this route when I get to setting this up, and probably accept your answer around then if nobody else chimes in with anything more interesting. Thank you :)